# React Native + Firebase: Is it possible to render multiple data value in different ref?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Data Structure example:

```
  "post": {
    "postId": {
      "name": ".....",
      "data1": "....",
    },
  "users": {
    "userId": {
      "username": "....",
      "data2"
   }
  }
```

Is it possible to render (`data1`/`data2`) in the same listview?

like this:

```
_renderList(lists) {
  return(
     <View>
       <Text>{lists.data1}</Text>
       <Text>{lists.data2}</Text>
     </View>
  )
}
```

I try to set two `ref()` in constructor, but it doesn`t work:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanges: (row1, row2) => row1 !==row2,
    }),
  }
  this.listsRef = firebase.database().ref('post');
  this.listsUserRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid)
}
```